# htaccess rul won't fire

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rule set it up. The first 2 are working but the last one doesn't really want to fire

```
RewriteRule ^/Content/(.*)/(.*)$                    /?main=$1&headline=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/Content/(.*)$                         /?main=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/Content/(.*)$                            /?index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your second and third rule looks the same. If you want to fire the last two at the same time (in this context it doesn't make sense), just remove the [L], which command the parser to stop after a hit.